# Crystal Report - Suppressing formula based on two conditions

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal report & i stuck in a condition which is not executing due to improper coding. so please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.
Here in my report I wanted to display the sales person name but there are 2 categories in sales person i.e Product & Vertical.

P-XXX-James Koren
V-YYY-BBB-Aditi N

Here I just wanted to pick the sales person name in both categories & for that I used mid function as : Mid({Salesperson Name},11,155) this is for vertical sales person, and for product sales person i used mid function as Mid({Salesperson Name},7,155) both are working fine.

but I wanted to suppress the vertical sales person name if the sales order belongs to product person & vice versa

I tried If condition but its not working properly please insist me for how to combine the 2 formulas & suppress one formula if 2 formulas are evaluated.

Comment: Where is your code? show us.

Comment: how are you checking if sales order belongs to some person?

Comment: @psyco  Here I am pasting my code

Comment: select a.DocEntry,
b.SlpName,

CASE when b.SlpName Like 'V%' then 1 
when b.SlpName Like 'P%' then 2 
end slp  

from OINV a 
left join OSLP b on a.SlpCode=b.SlpCode
where a.DocEntry={?Dockey@}

Comment: @Siva plz go through the above code,

Comment: post your full if condition and also your supression formulas that you are using.

Comment: @Prati better you put your code into the question section.It would be easier for us to look at your code than looking at comments.

Comment: @Prati. If you don't know how to put the code with proper intention than read it from here. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: select 
a.DocEntry,b.SlpName,
CASE                                                                                                 when                                                                                         b.SlpName Like 'V%' then 1   
when                                                                                          b.SlpName Like 'P%' then 2 
end slp  

from OINV a 
left join OSLP b on a.SlpCode=b.SlpCode
where                                                                                             a.DocEntry={?Dockey@}

Comment: @psyco : I tried to post the code in question section but its not allowing me to post, so here I have pasted the code line by line

Comment: @Siva :   Mid({slp.SlpName},11,155)                                                         This is the formula which I have created to fetch only the sales person name except remaining characters  & it works fine for the vertical sales person                                                                                                         For product sales person the formula is Mid({slp.SlpName},7,155) .

Comment: @Prati just put 4 spaces before every line of your code and see the magic of markdown.

Answer (score 0):

you can use if condition on `suppress` like

```
If
({your field} = "P" and //product or  you can use the query here to find P
PageNumber > 1)
then false        //don't Supress 
else true        //Supress
```

you can use the same formula on other field's `suppress` like

```
If
({your field} = "V" and //Vertical or you can use the query here to find V
 PageNumber > 1)
 then false        //don't Supress 
 else true        //Supress
```

Comment: E Habiba Thanks for the response :)

Comment: @psyco Thanks for the response. The issue is solved now & report working properly :)

Comment: @Siva Thanks for the response. The issue is solved now & report working properly :)